# ReactJS - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, uuid

I am trying to make a contact-manager-app from a YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0riHps91AzE&lc=Ugybk5M3ofjHsO8uHjd4AaABAg.9WHwkOL6qXV9WJu89p6VTV

Every time, I enter the inputs and click Add, the following error pops-up:
[the screen-shot of the main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l28zY.png)

I also get "*6 moderate severity vulnerabilities*" while downloading uuidv4. ( Put just in case, if it might help )

Also got "*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\loki\OneDrive\Desktop\ReactJS-YouTube\contact-app\node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib*"

Here are all my files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { uuid } from "uuidv4";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
import ContactList from "./ContactList";

function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, { id: uuid(), ...contact }]);
  };

  const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id;
    });

    setContacts(newContactList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts) setContacts(retriveContacts);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ContactList.js

```
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const ContactList = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    const deleteContactHandler = (id) => {
        props.getContactId(id);
    };

    const renderContactList = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
        return(
          <ContactCard contact={contact} clickHandler = { deleteContactHandler } key = { contact.id}/>
        );
    })
    return(
        <div className="ui celled list">
            {renderContactList}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactList;
```

ContactCard.js

```
import React from "react";
import user from "../images/user.jpg";

const CardContact = (props) => {
    const {id, name, email} = props.contact;
    return(
        <div className="item">
            <img className="ui avatar image" src={user} alt="user" />
              <div className="content">
                  <div className="header">{name}</div>
                  <div>{email}</div>
              </div>
              <i className="trash alternate outline icon"
                style={{color:"red",marginTop:"7px"}}
                onClick={() => props.clickHandler(id)}>
              </i>
          </div>
    );
};

export default CardContact;
```

AddContact.js

```
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
  };

  add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.name === "" || this.state.email === "") {
      alert("ALl the fields are mandatory!");
      return;
    }
    this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui main">
        <h2>Add Contact</h2>
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.add}>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <button className="ui button blue">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContact;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**From the `uuidv4` npm page:**
Most of the functionality of `uuidv4` module is already included in `uuid` since version 8.3.0, so most of the functions of `uuidv4` module have already been marked as deprecated.

So, importing `uuidv4` module in your `App.js` is causing this error.

You can upgrade to the latest version of `uuid` library to get rid of this error.

Run these commands in the terminal in your project directory.

```
npm uninstall uuidv4
npm install uuid
```

And now, in `App.js` import `uuid` module instead of `uuidv4`

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

And now, you can use `uuid()` function to create UUIDs

To check more about `uuid`, you can see there documentation: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#quickstart

Comment: I am also getting the same error...while following the video tutorial mentioned in question. Resolved the issue with uninstalling uuidv4 and installing uuid.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js:

On each `useEffect` (page renders) you are calling `setContract` , on `useEffect` below you are watching that contract as dependency , so it's rendering when contract is changing

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts) setContacts(retriveContacts);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
```

Comment: Ohh, ok. So is the rendering here, good or bad? And how is it related to the error I am getting?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the uuidv4 with the command `npm uninstall uuidv4` and installing the latest version of uuid with the command `npm install uuid` worked for me.

After installing the package import it as `import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'`;